Looking For An Episode of the Outer Limits Featuring a Doppelganger and an Alien
I'm looking for an episode of an anthology series, which I believe to be Outer Limits, although it could also be something like the Twilight Zone.
It's in English broadcast on American Television and I believe it was filmed in black and white.
The Plot has something to do with an alien escaping from an Alien Museum Exhibit and some man whose first or last name may be Henderson is somehow involved with the Alien, but the story has some kind of plot twist, where the man I believe to be called Henderson, is actually a doppelganger of some sort, and somehow the original Henderson's wife, is the key to figuring it out.
I watched this late one night over ten years ago on tv -- it was a rerun marathon, but was never able to remember much else and never seemed to be able to find it. Any help would be appreciated!

Sounds like the Outer Limits episode The Duplicate Man (Season 2, Episode 13) from 1964.

It is the year 2025; fourteen years previously wealthy research academic Henderson James had Captain Karl Emmet smuggle a Megasoid to Earth. It is illegal to possess a Megasoid as they are highly dangerous, always thinking about killing, unless in a reproductive cycle, which this one now is. When the Megasoid escapes to hide amongst the stuffed exhibits at a nearby space zoo, James, lacking the courage to track it down and kill it himself, has a clone of himself illegally made for the purpose [...]
Duplicate James meets the real James wife, Laura, who sees in him a more youthful version of her husband before he became obsessed with studying the Megasoid. [...] Entering his home, James meets his duplicate; seeing a more compassionate version of himself gives him the courage to kill the alien, as he believes Laura would be happier with the duplicate James.

Here are a couple of pictures from the episode:
 

Oh yes! I believe this is it! Thanks SO much!! I really want to rewatch it!! :)
